# webbrowser div border color

Tags: html, vb.net, webbrowser-control

I have a project using vb.net web browser to show some html files.

Those files have no border div inside. those files are ok by using IE and firefox, but open by the webbrowser it have color border at edge of each image. i tried to set border to 0px, set to transparent, set border to none, etc, still didn't solve the problem.

It looks like the webbrowser add those color border by itself...
here are the sample code, notice i have lot of similar lines like below to arrange those images.

```html
<div style="position: absolute; z-index: 1; left: 2697.6px; top: 3372px;" >
   <img src= "Images\1.jpg" alt="1" name="1"/>
</div>
```

Comment: try setting outline: 0;

Comment: I have edited your title. Please see, "[Should questions include “tags” in their titles?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19190/)", where the consensus is "no, they should not".

Comment: post URL to your page. That code is perfect on itself.